# Contact from join in EF

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following problem with EF and linq2sql using the two tables

Table1:

```
Id | Name
1  | Name1
2  | Name2
```

Table 2:

```
Id | Table1Id | Name
1  | 1        | SomeText1
2  | 1        | SomeText2
3  | 2        | SomeText3
```

I'd like to create a linq2sql query for get a resultset with template as

```
Table1Id:contact(Table2.Name+";")
```

for example

```
1:SomeText1;SomeText2
2:SomeText3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a few spare minutes this morning so please find below a sample implementation. In addition to the tables you specified to achieve what you want you will need to add an association between the two tables (many to many). This will run on a join table and add a navigation property to both of your entities.

The query below is essentially saying select out the table 1 entries and include the associated records from the Table2 navigation property. For the example I turned off Lazy Loading in the context (which you should do nearly all the time as it will cause issues cross tier and/or when serializing in your application).

```
        // db first
        using (var db = new SO15312066Entities())
        {
            // iterate over table 1, with join values from 2
            var query = db.Table1.Include("Table2");

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", item.Id, string.Join(";", item.Table2.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()));
            }
        }

        //output
        //1:SomeText1;SomeText2
        //2:SomeText3
```

The assumptions for this implementation is that it's EF database first (as you originally said you were having the issue in EF). SO15312066Entities is the ObjectContext for the query.

I've not checked how well this will perform, I will leave it up to you in your actual implementation.